# Horizontal pink line on my HP Pavilion 15, how do I fix it?

Tags: hp-pavilion, laptop-repair, laptop-display, pixels, hp-laptop

I use my 1yr old HP Pavilion for WFH, so its on for around 12 hrs or so every single day.

Yesterday, I put it on sleep mode and when I turn it on today I see a pinkish horizontal line over the screen in the middle from one edge to another.
I tried restarting and adjusting the resolution but to no avail.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkjr2.jpg

What is the issue here and what should I do?

Comment: Can you make a photo to show the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Connect an external monitor. If that shows a good picture then you know it is most likely your LCD panel in the laptop that needs replacing. If the external monitor is showing the same issues, you are having problems with the GPU on the logic board and will have to at least disassemble your laptop to inspect. In the second case I suggest you go to a computer repair shop.

Comment: Given it happened over night, it is more likely a driver update, does not necessarily have to be a hardware issue.

Comment: @LPChip - Drivers are not installed while in sleep mode (or when you resume from that mode). Now the restarting the author could have done that.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows update is notorious for waking the computer, perform updates and putting it back to sleep (most of the time). A driver update could also have been installed before the sleep and the wake reïnitialized the driver.

Comment: @lpchip Surely different resolutions would not show a pink line in the same place?  I guess you could boot I to the UEFI and if the pink line still exists it indicates a hardware problem.

Comment: @davidgo agreed, but I learned that people don't always tell everything. The pink line could have moved during resolution change or it can still be a driver issue. I've seen stuff like this with a faulty driver and solved it by uninstalling that driver completely then installed it again. I agree with what you say, but I can't rule it out completely.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that an update happened overnight. Also I've tried different resolutions, but the pink line doesn't moves. It only changes colour or camouflages under a white screen, for ex. Gmail. Next I've tried taking a screenshot and the line doesn't gets reflected over there. So it's a monitor fault most probably IMO. Now I've tried flashing the 'Dead/stuck Pixel' videos several times but still no luck.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/iXltWt1

Comment: Take a screenshot. View it resized so the line would not be in exactly the same place on the screen. If the line is on the screenshot, it's a software/driver issue. If it's not there at all [which is the result I expect] it's a hardware issue, screen needs replacing.